# Retrofit does not show any data

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

I am trying to retrieve/fetch data from server using retrofit and Rxjava to show data in recycler view. The code do not detect any error but still no data is shown. please check my code and help where am I mistaken.
**Here is my API**
https://www.testing.albassamapp.com/api/familymembers/v2

Here is my data class
Code:

```
data class Profile(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("father_name")
    val fatherName: String,
    @SerializedName("profile_picture_square")
    val profilePicture: String
)
```

Here is my interface:

```
interface ProfileApi {
    
    @GET("familymembers/v2")
    //single is observable it emit one variable and then close
    fun getProfiles(): Single<List<Profile>>
}
```

Here is my service class:

```
class ProfileService {
   private val BASE_URL = "https://www.testing.albassamapp.com/api/"

    private val api:ProfileApi

    init {
        api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ProfileApi::class.java)
    }

    fun getProfile(): Single<List<Profile>> {
        return api.getProfiles()
    }

}
```

Here is my listViewModel:

```
class ListViewModel:ViewModel() {

    private val profileService = ProfileService()
    private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

    //for live data
    val profiles = MutableLiveData<List<Profile>>()
    val profileLoadingError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    fun refresh() {
        fetchProfiles()
    }
    private fun fetchProfiles() {
        loading.value = true
        disposable.add(
            profileService.getProfile()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<List<Profile>>() {
                    override fun onSuccess(value: List<Profile>?) {
                        profiles.value = value
                        profileLoadingError.value = false
                        loading.value = false
                    }
                    override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                        profileLoadingError.value = true
                        loading.value = false
                    }
                })
        )
    }
    override fun onCleared() {
        disposable.clear()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can start debugging the response by logging it step by step, the code looks just fine to me

Comment: Code is correct but i do not understand how to get the response from api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one mistake serlizable is wrong based on reponse for api, api response is json object contain list of profile you change return in api interface
First create object

this your data class

```
 data class Profile(
@SerializedName("id")
val id: Int,
@SerializedName("name")
val name: String,
@SerializedName("father_name")
val fatherName: String,
@SerializedName("profile_picture_square")
val profilePicture: String
)
```

Add new class in your data class

```
    data class Result(
     @SerializedName("Status")
      val status: Int,
      @SerializedName("Message")
      val message: String,
    @SerializedName("Data")
    val data: List<Profile>
     )
```

your interface will be like this after change

```
interface ProfileApi {

@GET("familymembers/v2")
//single is observable it emit one variable and then close
fun getProfiles(): Single<Result>
}
```

your service will be like this

```
class ProfileService {
 private val BASE_URL = "https://www.testing.albassamapp.com/api/"

 private val api:ProfileApi

 init {
    api = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ProfileApi::class.java)
}

fun getProfile(): Single<Result> {
    return api.getProfiles()
}

}
```

your view model will be like this

```
class ListViewModel: ViewModel() {

 private val profileService = ProfileService()
 private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

  //for live data
  val profiles = MutableLiveData<List<Profile>>()
  val profileLoadingError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

   val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    fun refresh() {
      fetchProfiles()
  }
  private fun fetchProfiles() {
     loading.value = true
     disposable.add(
       profileService.getProfile()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<Result>() {
         override fun onSuccess(result: Result) {
        if(result.status==200){
          profiles.value = result.data
          profileLoadingError.value = false
        }else{
          // in case exception or message
          profileLoadingError.value = true
        }
        loading.value = false
      }

      override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        profileLoadingError.value = true
        loading.value = false
      }

    })
  )
  }
 override fun onCleared() {
  disposable.clear()
   }
 }
```

Comment: I do not understand what you have said.. can you please amend my code

Comment: Sir when I have used your code, the result line in list view has showed error
Code line: DisposableSingleObserver<Result>()
Error: One type argument expected for class Result <out T>

Comment: @EhtadaJodat sorry i edit again viewModel class will work fine with you
your problem how convert json to model class there is plugin in android studio you can use it jsonTokotlinClass

Comment: Thankyou Sir, Your code helped me a lot. Allah bless you.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified @yousef's answer above to the following because I could not edit for some reason and the English is a little unclear

You have one mistake the model is wrong based on response for api, api response is json object that contains list of other model object say `Profile` you must change the returned model in api interface like
First create model `Result`

```
data class Result(
 @SerializedName("Status")
 val status: Int,
 @SerializedName("Data")
 val data: List<Profile>
)
```

and then make a `Profile` class like so

```
data class Profile(
 @SerializedName("id")
 val id: Int
 @SerializedName("parent_id")
 val parentId: Int // and so on based on the fields you need
)
```

Just change  in your interface for api take object result like this

```
  fun getProfiles(): Single<Result>.
```

And then accordingly this will change the other code and you can get the `List<Profile>` property of the `Result` class by using getters which are provided by default in the data class of Kotlin

Additionally to reduce the headache while making a model from json, You can use websites like [Json2Kotlin](https://www.json2kotlin.com/)